# How to save data from Postman in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, postman

I try to send data from Postman to this function

```
    public function new(Request $request): Response
    {

      $tag = new Tag();
      $form = $this->createForm(TagType::class, $tag);
      $form->submit($request->request->all());

      if ($form->isValid()) {
          $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
          $entityManager->persist($tag);
          $entityManager->flush();
          $message = "Tag was successfully added";
          return new JsonResponse(array("message: $message"));
      }
      $errors = $form->getErrors();
      return new JsonResponse(array("message:$errors"));

    }
```

If i send data as 'form-data' i can save it to database.
But i can't understand how to accept 'raw' Json 'application/json'

I can only manually take value from Request with

```
$tagTitle = $request->query->get('title');
```

And i can't do it with some FOSUserBundle etc.
I can use only jms/serializer. If i will need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fetch the json from `$request->getContent()` first:

```
public function new(Request $request): Response
{

  $tag = new Tag();
  $form = $this->createForm(TagType::class, $tag);
  $form->submit(json_decode($request->getContent(), true));

  if ($form->isValid()) {
      $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
      $entityManager->persist($tag);
      $entityManager->flush();
      $message = "Tag was successfully added";
      return new JsonResponse(array("message: $message"));
  }
  $errors = $form->getErrors();
  return new JsonResponse(array("message:$errors"));

}
```

Comment: $form->submit(json_decode($request->getContent(), true)); // -- without body

and i have an error
"message:ERROR: This form should not contain extra fields.\n"
Know way to solve it?

Comment: Sorry I messed up the body with guzzle request... Wrote it from memory.

Comment: csrf protection disabled